# heap out of Memory E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 383385715-byte allocation

Tags: java, android

I am using the `Byte buffer` `allocate` method and it returned a heap out of memory error. This buffer used to read an audio file from my internal storage and decode it. I'm using audio player with cutter after which I faced this issue.

Comment: 365MB allocation is quite a lot. You don't usually get that much memory for a single application, depending on the manufacturer. Do you really need that much at once?

Answer (score 0):

Do not read the **whole** (especially a **large**) file into the memory **at once**.

You are cutting parts of the audio file.

Use a RandomAccessFile if you need to read, say, the middle part of the file, or at a specific location you know. Or, read starting from the start of the file, byte by byte, but don't store unnecessary information into program memory. Say, if you need to index parts of the file, store these offsets into memory, but not the rest of the data from the file.

Actually, a [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) contains most of the functions that you may want to use from `ByteBuffer`, like `writeShort`, `readShort`, etc.

If you would like to copy part of the file into another file/stream, wrap another `OutputStream` and copy the bytes at smaller portions.

For example, if you want to write a file with 65536 `short`s, from -32768 to 32767:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
for(short s = Short.MIN_VALUE; s <= Short.MAX_VALUE; s++){
    file.writeShort(s);
}
file.close();
```